# Appending an array in swift, having problems

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cloudkit

I am getting the error 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'append' for results that I am trying to post to an array.  I'm not sure how to fix the error, as I thought my code was correct.  Can someone help me make the proper adjustments?  My code is as follows:

```
import CloudKit
import UIKit
import Foundation

class Items {
    var theSelfie: [String]

    init(record: CKRecord) {
        println("init")
        var record: CKRecord
        var iama: String
        var youarea: String
        var image: CKAsset? // tried also initializing the CKAsset separately
        var postPic: UIImage?

        let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
        let data = CKRecord(recordType: "theUsers")

        var predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let myQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "theUsers", predicate: predicate)

        var mySelfie = theSelfie

        publicDB.performQuery(myQuery, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            } else {
                for record in results{
                    let aselfie = data.objectForKey("selfie")
                        aselfie.append[mySelfie]()
                        return ()
                    }        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this meant to be: `append[mySelfie]`? Why are there brackets? What is `CKRecord`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of objectForKey is AnyObject!

The type `AnyObject` doesn't have a method named `append`. You'll need to cast the return value to the correct type.

In addition, I don't think I see you ever put an entry in `data` with key "selfie". If you want it to be an array then somewhere you need to call `data.setObject`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `aselfie` from a dictionary. The dictionary returns objects of type `AnyObject`. Since you seem confident, that's it's an `Array` you can cast it to `Array` or `NSArray`.

```
let aselfie = data.objectForKey("selfie") as Array
```

Comment: If you cast as an array like that, changes won't get passed back to the object.  It would have to be cast as (and backed by) an NSMutableArray.  Otherwise it's got to be read/modify/write.

Comment: You are correct. A mutable copy has to be created first.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast aselfie to array then call its append method not its subscript

```
if let aselfie = data.objectForKey("selfie") as? [AnyObject] // if aselfie is supposed to hold object of single type case it as [ObjcetsToHold]
                    aselfie.append(mySelfie)
                    return ()
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `aselfie.append[mySelfie]()` is valid Swift syntax. Does it even compile? Maybe you meant `aselfie.append(mySelfie)`?

Also, how do you know that `aselfie` is an `Array`? You should cast it:

```
let aselfie = data.objectForKey("selfie") as? Array<Whatever>
    aselfie.append[mySelfie]()
    return ()
}
```

Comment: `Array<Whatever>` is the old syntax, now you need to use `[Whatever]`

Comment: @Emilie You can use either... The old syntax is `Whatever[]`. As a matter of fact, `[Wharever]` is a shortcut for `Array<Whatever>`